# Filtering and Averaging

Tags: syntax, filtering

I have a large 3D matrix (Length = 300k) with duplicated values

```
list={{1,1,a},{1,1,b},{1,2,c},{1,2,d},{1,3,e}...}
```

If the first and second elements exactly match another entry, I'd like the 3rd element to be averaged

For example, as the first two elements of `{1,1,a}` and `{1,1,b}` match, we should take `Mean[a,b]` and leave just one entry in a new matrix of `{1,1,Mean[a,b]}`.

I can get `Tally` to find the duplicates, but it takes a really long time for the bigger list. Any suggestions?

Tally[list, #1[[1]] === #2[[1]] && #1[[2]] === #2[[2]] &]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Values @ GroupBy[list, Most, Mean]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1, (a + b)/2}, {1, 2, (c + d)/2}, {1, 3, e}}
> ```

Also

```
Mean /@ GatherBy[list, Most]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1, (a + b)/2}, {1, 2, (c + d)/2}, {1, 3, e}}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Converting them to associations and using `Merge` might be a good solution:

```
In[1]:= KeyValueMap[Append, 
 Merge[<|#[[1 ;; 2]] -> #[[3]]|> & /@ {{1, 1, a}, {1, 1, b}, {1, 2, c}, {1, 2, d}, {1, 3, e}}, Mean]]
Out[1]= {{1, 1, (a + b)/2}, {1, 2, (c + d)/2}, {1, 3, e}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Is this faster and works correctly for all your cases?

```
list={{1,1,a},{1,1,b},{1,2,c},{1,2,d},{1,3,e}};
Mean/@Split[Sort[list],Most[#1]==Most[#2]&]
(*{{1, 1, (a + b)/2}, {1, 2, (c + d)/2}, {1, 3, e}}*)
```